# Is there any way to turn a token into a nontoken?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is there anything in Magic that can turn a token permanent into a nontoken permanent?

Comment: In general, this is not the right way to handle updating information in existing posts. You should either comment on the answer asking whether it is up to date, or put a bounty on the question to ask for updated information. I am not closing this question because it does not directly match any existing question, but I have edited it to make it stand alone without referring to the other answer, and to remove references to the specific timeframe.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Within the actual rules definition for "Token", such a thing really isn't possible.

> 111. Tokens
>
> > 111.1. Some effects put tokens onto the battlefield. A token is a marker used to represent **any permanent that isn't represented by a card**.

With this definition, something becoming a nontoken really means that the thing becomes a card. And to become a card, you need a physical real-world card to have a card in general.

So as long as something is a permanent, and it isn't represented by a card, then it is a token. The closest thing you could do is replace a token with a different non-token that does the same thing... i.e. you could have an ability that says "sacrifice target Forest token. Choose a Forest card you own from outside the game and put it on the battlefield."

But if an ability said something like "target token becomes a non-token", it would just be confusing... Even though effects on cards can override any rules in the rulebook; an effect like this would basically be just redefining the word "token" as it is in the rules. Assuming that you aren't talking about it actually becoming a card; then it becomes an entirely new thing that is a concept never thought of in the rules... a permanent that is neither a token nor a card. You would need to alter a ton of other rules to make it work... what happens when this non-token, non-card enters a graveyard? You would likely need to replace the rules that make tokens in graveyards cease to exist with a rule that applies to all non-cards in graveyards instead.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, I'm looking for ways to expand my card count in-game, like having a graveyard with more creatures / cards than are in my+my opponents' decks

Comment: Graveyard Busybody is a silver bordered card that would make all graveyards your graveyard instead of whatever player they normally belong to. There are spells like the Wishes that bring in cards from outside the game (IE in your sideboard) but other than that your card count will always be based on what you started with in deck.

Comment: @Malady, if your real objective is to "expand my card count in-game" that makes a reasonable question in and of itself, as there are lots of ways to do that, particularly in casual/non-tournament settings.  They aren't necessarily obvious however...

Comment: @John - I'm looking for ways to infinitely expand the number of "things that will graveyard when killed / used". Since that seems to be cards, and only tokens can be created infinitely, it appears the answer to my question is "Not possible right now"?

Comment: @Malady, I think you need to reread my comment.

Comment: @John - Well, at your advice, here's my question: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/54310/how-to-get-the-most-cards-possible-getting-more-cards-mid-game

Answer (score 13):

GendoIkari's answer is technically correct... A token by definition is not a card, but misses one new corner case to have emerged from Ikoria: Mutate

Mutate can take a card (non-token) and combine it with an existing permanent (non-human creatures only, but tokens are a valid target) to modify the existing permanent, using one of the two as the template... You can therefore have a creature card be technically a token (The token's stats are used as the 'top' or default state) or have a token become a non-token (the mutate card goes on top and changes the default state), the second of which results in a permanent that has changed from being a token to not being token.

But honestly, most people just use a card like Skullclamp or Foster to get non-token cards from a token :-p